# How to install firesheep on windows

Tags: mozilla, winpcap

I tried to use the tutorial to install firesheep, and it said to install WinPcap to run the file. When I tried to run the file on Firefox, it just gave a blank webpage. I watched YouTube tutorials and followed the instructions on this http://pinglio.com/2010/11/how-to-install-and-use-firesheep/ website. Any suggestions to help for a windows user?

Answer (score 1):

I now know I have to install an earlier version of firefox from the same website from the comments.